# sql injection with password compared from keyboard

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-injection

im tryng to realise i java application, and i've been struggling with security beacause im new to this.
so to avoid sql injection in authetification comparing the password directly from keyboard.

so i want to know if there's any possible way we can still do an sql injection in this code?

```
login = in.readLine();
pass = in.readLine();
resultat = conn.getConnexion().createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users_frontale WHERE login ='"+login+"'");

                if(resultat.first())    
                    if(resultat.getString("password").equals(pass))
                        connexion=true;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: yes, you can enter login like `'; drop table users_frontale; ---`

Comment: No need to reinvent a wheel: use prepared statements.

Comment: To avoid SQL Injection, read up on OWASP SQL Injection guidelines.

Comment: Besides the obvious SQL injection problem, you are storing passwords unhashed which is also a security flaw.

Comment: Have you thought about using `Hibernate` instead of `JDBC`